# Understanding properties syntax and functionality in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, properties

I'm using python 2.7, I've created a class, and I got some property in it. I'm instantiating an object out of the class with some value input. The class:

```
class Prop(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.A = data
```

and the getter/setter:

```
@property
def A(self):
    return self._A

@A.setter
def A(self, data):
    self._A = data
```

The above works fine. Inside my main script I'm instantiating:

```
prop_demo = Prop('some text')
```

However, if I change inside `__init__` the `self.A = data` with `self._A = data`, then `A` doesn't pass though the setter, then I think it misses a bit the point of having a setter. I changed it since it seems more intuitive to me to use the `_` for an inner class variable, and doing `self.A = data` seems to me something that an instance of that class should do (outside the class, in my main script).

I have 2 questions:

1. Why do we do `self.A` and not `self._A` in the init? maybe I'm missing something regarding the importance of `_` with python class variables?
2. Why inside the class init we need to call the setter, and the setter is not automatically executed when creating the object? Why isn't the setter automatically being executed when I instantiate an object?

Comment: Because the property is `A`, not `_A`. Note, for something like this, you shouldn't be using a property at all, and just a normal attribute. Your setter/getters don't *do anything*, so they are completely unecessary. In any case, if you *are* going to use a property, then you *should* use that property inside the class, that's the whole point of encapsulation (unless, you want to *break* encapsulation for some reason, e.g. performance...). But again, simply put, the property is `.A`, not `._A`. Those are two different things.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I intentionally simplified my setter function to 'do nothing' for the simplicity of explaining my concern. Of-course my property is A, that's how I access it outside the class init scope. But why not using `_` inside the class scope?

Comment: I don't know how to be more clear. `.A` is not `._A` in the same way `.foo` is not `.bar`. The fact the the only difference is a leading underscore doesn't matter, to the language itself, they are two different attributes. Your property is `.A`. It is totally distinct from `._A`, which is just a normal attribute, which you use in `.A`, but that is neither here nor there. Use `._x` instead of `._A` and maybe that will make it clear?